# matching two text files using cat and grep

Tags: bash

I have two text file, one an input.txt file which looks like so:

```
john j william
james slate
david wallace
..
```

and then I have a reference.txt file which also has names:

```
joseph william
raj kumar
william hague
david alexander
```

I want to know if the last name of `input.txt` is present as the last name in `reference.txt`. I just want a count of how many are present and how many arent present (yea I know this can mean fale positive for being present, but I just want to explore this data and iam more interested in the absent count)

Normally Id do :

```
cat input.txt | grep "<the_last_name>"

where `the_last_name` is each name from reference.txt
```

but how do I do this programatically on the input.txt and get count of the not found ones?

Comment: Im having trouble understanding exactly what the output should be, but as you want to compare files I think [comm](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html) may be of use. Something like `comm -1 <(sort input.txt) <(sort reference.txt)` would give you lines in `reference.txt` not in `input.txt`

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge yea that seems to work but Id like to restrict it to only the last name on the input.txt file

Comment: What do you mean by "yea I know this can mean fale positive for being present"? Why would anything mean getting a false positive? Please [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input as I see from the answers we're all making different assumptions about what " I just want a count of how many are present and how many arent present" means.

Comment: Regarding "Normally Id do : `cat input.txt | grep "<the_last_name>"`". Now THAT would produce false matches and there's no way to make it robust without introducing a call to sed or similar as you need regexp anchors to avoid substring or wrong part of the line matches but also you need to escape regexp characters like `.` that can appear in names.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you just want the occurrences (frequency) of last names from `input.txt` in `reference.txt`, then you can do that easily with `awk`, e.g.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$NF]=0; next} $NF in a {a[$NF]++} END {for (i in a) print i " - " a[i]}' input.txt reference.txt
```

Where the first rule `FNR == NR {a[$NF]=0; next}` simply creates an array indexed by the last names reading from the first file. The next rule `$NF in a {a[$NF]++}` updates the array with the count of last names from `references.txt` that were present in `input.txt`. Finally the `END` rule just loops over the array printing the occurrences for each of the name in `input.txt` as found in `reference.txt`, e.g.

**Use/Output**

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$NF]=0; next} $NF in a {a[$NF]++} END {for (i in a) print i " - " a[i]}' input.txt reference.txt
slate - 0
william - 1
wallace - 0
```

Where `william` appears 1 time in `reference.txt` and neither `slate` nor `wallace` appear in `reference.txt`.

If you prefer a more readable awk-script form, you can write it as follows, e.g.

```
#!/bin/awk -f

FNR == NR {     # scan 1st file create array a indexed by last name
  a[$NF] = 0
  next
}

$NF in a {      # in 2nd file, if last name in array a, increment count
  a[$NF]++
}

END {           # loop over names in array a outputting count
  for (i in a)
    print i " - " a[i]
}
```

Then simply make the script executable and pass the filenames as arguments. With the script in `input-reference-count.awk` you would do:

```
$ chmod +x input-reference-count.awk
$ ./input-reference-count.awk input.txt reference.txt
slate - 0
william - 1
wallace - 0
```

---

If you also wanted to shown names from `reference.txt` not in `input.txt` you could capture those names in a second `b[]` array and then output them after the count for the names in the first. In the same script format, you would have:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

FNR == NR {     # scan 1st file create array a indexed by last name
  a[$NF] = 0
  next
}

{      
  if ($NF in a) # in 2nd file, if last name in array a, increment count
    a[$NF]++
  else          # otherwise save name not present in input in b array
    b[$NF]++
}

END {           # loop over names in array a outputting count
  for (i in a)
    print i " - " a[i]
  print "---- not present in first file ----"
  for (i in b)  # then names in b for names not in first file
    print i " - " b[i]
}
```

Running in the same manner would now produce output for each name in both files, e.g.

```
$ ./input-reference-count.awk input.txt reference.txt
slate - 0
william - 1
wallace - 0
---- not present in first file ----
alexander - 1
hague - 1
kumar - 1
```

If I missed your point, let me  know and I'm happy to help further.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { names[$NF]; next }
    { cnt[$NF in names]++ }
    END { printf "present: %d\nabsent: %d\n", cnt[1], cnt[0] }
' reference.txt input.txt
present: 1
absent: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I read the last names from `reference.txt` into an array `reference_names` and then, I read each line from `input.txt`, extracts the last name, and checks if it exists in `reference_names`. If it doesn't, it increments the `not_found_count` variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

#reading the contents of input.txt and reference.txt files    
BEGIN {
    while ((getline < "reference.txt") > 0) {
        reference_names[$NF]
    }
}

#checking if each last name from input.txt is present in reference.txt
{
    last_name = $NF
    if (!(last_name in reference_names)) {
        not_found_count++
    }
}

#printing the count of last names not found
END {
    print "Count of last names not found:", not_found_count+0
}
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f script.awk input.txt 
Count of last names not found: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like simple with awk. The following might get you started:

```
awk '
    # if the first file
    NR==FNR{
       # add last element to the map as a key
       last[$NF]=1;
    }
    # if second file 
    NR!=FNR{
      # if last field is in previosu file last fields
      if ($NF in last) {
            # increment count
            count[$NF]++;
      } else {
            # increment another array count
            notpresent[$NF]++;
      }
    }
    END{
       # print the counts
      for (i in count) print(i, count[i]);
      # print missing presents
      print("--- notpresent");
      for (i in notpresent) print(i, notpresent[i]);
   }' file1 file2
```

outputs:

```
william 1
--- notpresent
alexander 1
hague 1
kumar 1
```

Comment: I think I must have screwed up reading the question, I got a different count :-(